# Logging into google through mIRC without openID or otherwise

Tags: sockets, mirc

I need to login to google to access a private spreadsheet through mIRC. I can store the email and password in a variable, no problem; I just don't know the easiest way to actually login - I want it fully automatic, no user prompt required.

I tried this so far, but it didn't work..

http://pastebin.com/r57KQ1DP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy answer, I'm sorry.
The google login is very complicated because:

- It uses multible set-cookie lines in the header reply
- It has hidden fields which seems to be used as security method (you would need to request the login site first and store those values and send them with the login-request to make your login-try valid)
- You manipulate the cookie and how it's stored and sent in the next request, this can also have an effect to the login.

There is only one suggestion I can make to you: Download the firefox addon [Live HTTP headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) and try to follow what your browser sends and act like it.

Comment: I suggest checking out httpfox; it has an easier to use interface. However, thankyou, I ended up using oauth - google doesn't want to be "broken into" so to speak :P